# How to declare a TypeScript indexer that accepts string|number?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a `d.ts` file for an API which has a collection object representing an *ordered* collection of key-value pairs. The keys and values are all strings. Thus, the behavior is:

- `thing["foo"]` returns the string value of the pair where key is "foo"
- `thing[1]` returns the string value of the second pair in the ordered collection
- `thing.length` returns the count of key-value pairs as a number

I tried the following, but it produced the error `"An index signature parameter must be type 'string' or 'number'`:

```
declare class FrobCollection {
    [index: string|number] : string;

}
```

Is there a way to model the behavior of this object correctly in TypeScript?

**EDIT:** I found a way to model the two indexers, but still can't get the `length` property to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - thing["foo"] returns the string value of the pair where key is "foo"
> - thing[1] returns the string value of the second pair in the ordered collection
> - thing.length returns the count of key-value pairs as a number

The problem is that the first bullet is not true for all values of `"foo"`. For example, `thing["0"]` is a string, but `thing["length"]` is a number, and for an arbitrary string `x` you can't actually predict the type of `thing[x]`

The accurate definition for this type is:

```
declare class HeaderCollection {
    length: number;
    [index: number]: string;
    [key: string]: number|string;
}
```

where it's up to the caller to ensure that they actually indexed by a value that didn't match up with some reserved name like `length`, or a string that was actually a number.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's unfortunate the library implemented this the way they did; it's going to make declaring any function signatures on this type very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that appears to work, though I haven't been able to test it fully yet.

```
declare class HeaderCollection {
    [index: number] : string;
    [key: string] : string;
}
```

I thought this would complain because TypeScript normally doesn't allow overloading, but it appears that's not the case this time. However, I'm still unable to declare the `length` property of type `number`, so I'm not out of the woods yet.