# How do I declare Internet Explorer's `document.all[name: string]` indexer in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, internet-explorer

I'm converting some very old ASP.NET WebForms JavaScript specific to Internet Explorer 6-9 to TypeScript and I don't know how to declare Internet Explorer's various proprietary JavaScript DOM extensions.

For example, Internet Explorer's `document.all` collection allows elements to be indexed by name, whereas the `lib.dom.d.ts` interface for `HTMLAllCollection` only exposes the `[index: number]` indexer:

#### lib.dom.d.ts:

```
interface HTMLAllCollection {

    readonly length: number;

    item(nameOrIndex?: string): HTMLCollection | Element | null;

    namedItem(name: string): HTMLCollection | Element | null;

    [index: number]: Element;
}
```

So I thought I'd extend this in my own code:

#### MyProject.ts

```
interface HTMLAllCollection {

    [name: string]: HTMLElement;
}
```

However this breaks everything because adding a string-indexer to an interface means that all other properties on the interface must also return the same type as the string-indexer (`HTMLElement`) which is incorrect in this case because, for example, the `length` property must return a `number`. This explained in this article here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html

Fortunately [the `namedItem` getter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms536634%28v=vs.94%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) was added in Internet Explorer 6 and the website I'm working on does not require IE 5.5 compatibility (phew!) so for now I can replace `document.all["name"].value = "bar"` with `document.all.namedItem("name").value = "bar"` but there are other DOM interfaces with similar tricks that I might encounter in future - so how can I handle those correctly?

Answer (score 0):

What about declare an indexer having both `string` and `number`? The article you providing has the example of having both `string` and `number` indexers. The definition for this type is like this:

```
interface ArrStr {
  [key: string]: string | number; // Must accommodate all members    
  [index: number]: string; // Can be a subset of string indexer    
  // Just an example member
  length: number;
}
```

Reference link: [Index Signatures](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html)

[How to declare a TypeScript indexer that accepts string|number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862033/how-to-declare-a-typescript-indexer-that-accepts-stringnumber)

Comment: This is not possible for `HTMLAllCollection` because of `LegacyUnenumerableNamedProperties` (see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#the-htmlallcollection-interface )